# Python keep multiple counters in one recursion function

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

I am trying to count the number of python files and non-python files in a path recursively.

```
import os
def main():
    #path = input('Enter an existing path to a file or directory: ')
    path ='/Users/ziyuanhan/PycharmProjects/lab6/'
    print(count_file(path, counter={'py':0, 'non_py':0}))

def count_file(path,counter):
    if os.path.isfile(path):
        if path.endswith('.py') :
            counter['py']+=1
            return path, counter
        else:
            counter['non_py']+=1
            return path, counter
    elif os.path.isdir(path):
        for files in os.listdir(path):
            print(files)
            path = os.path.abspath(files)
            print(path)
            count_file(path, counter)
        return path, counter

main()
```

The few problems I have is

1. I had trouble in keeping multiple counters in one recursion function.
2. Also the return I want is a dictionary format, but I can only do it this way because I have to return it with path.
3. I use `print(files)` to check if the function is working alright, but it shows a lot more files(the top 7 files) I never seen in my folder, why is this happening?

When `print(files)`

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3.5 

/Users/ziyuanhan/PycharmProjects/lab7/recursive_dir_traversal.py
.DS_Store
/Users/ziyuanhan/PycharmProjects/lab7/.DS_Store
.idea
/Users/ziyuanhan/PycharmProjects/lab7/.idea
lab7.iml
/Users/ziyuanhan/PycharmProjects/lab7/lab7.iml
misc.xml
/Users/ziyuanhan/PycharmProjects/lab7/misc.xml
modules.xml
/Users/ziyuanhan/PycharmProjects/lab7/modules.xml
workspace.xml
/Users/ziyuanhan/PycharmProjects/lab7/workspace.xml
km_mi_table.py
/Users/ziyuanhan/PycharmProjects/lab7/km_mi_table.py
km_to_miles.py
/Users/ziyuanhan/PycharmProjects/lab7/km_to_miles.py
wordfrequency.py
/Users/ziyuanhan/PycharmProjects/lab7/wordfrequency.py
('/Users/ziyuanhan/PycharmProjects/lab7/wordfrequency.py', {'non_py': 0, 'py': 0})
```

BTW we have to use recursive function, it is mandatory as the Prof requested.

Comment: How does this function know when to stop?

Comment: It stops when it has run through all the files and directories for the path I provided

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by 'stop'?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to iterate directory recursively yourself. You can use [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) which yields directories, files for you:

You cannot change local variable / argument of caller. How about returns `total_python`, `total_non_python` and use in caller like below?

```
def count_file(path):
    total_python, total_non_python = 0, 0
    for parent, directories, files in os.walk(path):
        for filename in files:
            if filename.lower().endswith('.py'):
                total_python += 1
            else:
                total_non_python += 1
    return total_python, total_non_python

def main():
    path = input('Enter a path to a file or directory: ')
    total_python, total_non_python = count_file(path)
    print(path, total_python, total_non_python)
```

Alternatively, [`os.scandir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.scandir) is also available since Python 3.5.

Comment: Thanks, os.walk does make the task easier but our prof force us to use recursive function

Comment: so the function has to have a base case and a recursive case

Comment: Not quite, it's a pproject

Comment: @Byron, Okay, then I will give you home hints instead of giving you direct code. (1) You need to call `count_file` recursively if the file is directory; current it ignore if the file is directory.  (2) `total_python += 1` does not affect caller's variable. In changes only in the caller. You'd better return the value and make it used outside the caller.

Comment: Hi I changed some of my code according to your suggestions, could you have another look at it please?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a dictionary as an argument to the function and change the values of the items in the dictionary.

First intialize the dictionary:

```
counters = {'py': 0, 'other': 0}
```

Then modify it inside the recursive function:

```
counters['py'] += 1
```

This will work because dictionaries are [mutable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8056130/immutable-vs-mutable-types).

Comment: Thanks! The dictionary counter works, but I don't know why the counter keeps giving me 0,0 if I input a path to a directory. Can you have a look please?

Comment: Hi sorry I forgot to update my question, it is in the question now, I changed some code according to your suggestion. There are multiple files in the input path to the directory, but the output is still (0,0)

Comment: The first error is that `path = os.path.abspath(files)` assumes that `files` is in the current folder, not the folder you are scanning. I think you meant to use `path = os.path.join(path, files)`. Even if you do that it doesn't work, because you are reusing the variable `path`. You could use another variable `path2` on that line and the following 2 and it works well.

Comment: You should never delete or edit parts of your question that already have an answer. You could add an **EDIT** at the bottom of the question and explain that you are adding that part to the question in reference to an answer or to a comment. Otherwise future readers will not understand why certain answers or comments were given

Answer (score 0):

This function takes a pathname and returns `(total_python, total_not_python)`. It calls itself on each entries in directories. This is meant to be as close to the given code as reasonable.

```
def count_file(path):
    if os.path.isfile(path):
        if path.endswith('.py') :
            return 1, 0
        else:
            return 0, 1
    elif os.path.isdir(path):
        total_python, total_not_python = 0, 0
        for files in os.listdir(path):
            print(files)
            path = os.path.join(path, files)
            subtotal_python, subtotal_python = count_file(path)
            total_python += subtotal_python
            total_not_python += subtotal_not_python
        return total_python, total_not_python
```

Comment: Thanks! But I don't know why the counter keeps giving me 0,0 if I input a path to a directory.